# How do i find out the JDK version Eclipse is using?

Tags: eclipse, java

I see JRE all over the place, but i can not be sure which JDK is compiling my code. How do i find out?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually Eclipse has its own compiler. You can develop java apps using only the JRE and Eclipse

Comment: Oh? Could you explain why that is?

Comment: I think the main reason is that unlike javac it can compile files incrementally as you edit them.

Comment: If Eclipse comes with its own JDK, why does it matter to set JAVA_HOME env path variable pointing to your JDK installation?

Answer (score 32):

You can still check/set which JDK version you want to compile to.  If you go to Window->Preferences, then click "Java" from the menu on the left and then "Compiler".  The first setting allows you to see which JDK version is being complied with.

I know this doesn't directly answer your question since JDK isn't actually compiling it, but hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You don't find JDK explicitly mentioned anywhere because way to point to a JDK is under the name of 'Installed JRE'. That is Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. This is useful when using m2e plugin.

secondly apart from having it's own built in compiler, it is recommended to you install one of your own to support development of Java programs. Except below from eclipse wiki [page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation) :

> *If you intend to use Eclipse for Java development, then you should install a JDK*