# How do I know the compiler version which the eclipse is using?

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

I am using `JRE` version `7` with my eclipse. How do I know the compiler version which the eclipse is using ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being utterly lazy to explorer menu items in the IDE.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate questions.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573836/how-do-i-find-out-the-jdk-version-eclipse-is-using

Answer (score 2):

goto

check for jdk

```
windows > preference > java > installed jre
```

check for eclipse's compiler compliance level

```
windows > preference > java > compiler
```

Comment: `windows > preference > java > installed jre` doesn't it mention the `jre version` ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be different for each project. Right click on the project, and go to Properties/Java Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Window/Preferences/Java/Compiler to see default configuration of your IDE. 
Check the project properties as well to be sure you do not have per-project configuration differ from default.