# Problem With running java minecraft & modding in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

i dont know how to describe it but here is the code ive put in eclipse + the guide i used

https://codakid.com/guide-to-minecraft-modding-with-java/

[2021-06-12 22:53:07] [INFO   ] Natives: C:\Users\amine\Desktop\mc gd hax\build\natives
[2021-06-12 22:53:07] [INFO   ] Main Class: net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch
[2021-06-12 22:53:07] [INFO   ] Srg2Mcp: C:\Users\amine\Desktop\mc gd hax\build\createSrgToMcp\output.srg
[2021-06-12 22:53:07] [INFO   ] Extra: []
[2021-06-12 22:53:07] [INFO   ] Running with arguments: [--version, 1.12, --assetIndex, 1.12, --assetsDir, C:\Users\amine.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\assets, --accessToken, {REDACTED}, --userProperties, [], --tweakClass, net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.(Launch.java:34)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
... 6 more

Answer (score 2):

Java 9 or later is not supported.
Make sure you are using java 8.

To see your current version, type this in the command line:

```
java -version
```

Comment: i am using version 8

Comment: Is eclipse using JDK 8? Eclipse could be using a bundled jdk.

Comment: so how to check

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't have eclipse installed,
but if you create a test project and use this as the main function
it will print out the version of the jdk:

`public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
    }`

Comment: You can set the version of jdk you want to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573847.